# x86 Remote Debugger Service on x64

Tags: remote-debugging

I've seen the same question in the link below but somehow it didn't work for me.

[x86 Remote Debugger Service on x64](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76939/x86-remote-debugger-service-on-x64)

when I'm running the MSVSMON.EXE - X86 i'm getting in the visual studio this error:

[image]

and when I'm running the x64 version of MSVSMON.EXE it shows:
[image]